# mackel-agent (のプラグイン) の動作ログは、どこから取得できますか？

Tags: untagged

mackerel-agent をインストール・問題なく動作しているホストに、プラグイン (mysql) の導入をしようとしました。結局、試行錯誤していった結果、問題なく動いたのですが、ふと、たとえばプラグイン関係のログなどは、どこかからか取得できなかったのか、と疑問に思いました。

## 質問

mackerel-agent をインストールしたホストの上で、 mackerel の動作ログはどこからか取得できますか？ ひとまず、 `/var/log` 直下にはそれっぽいものがないので、質問しています。

## インストール環境

- Amazon Linux 2
- [公式の itamae recipe](https://github.com/mackerelio/itamae-plugin-recipe-mackerel-agent) を利用してプロビジョニング

Answer (score 0):

agent のログ出力先は `/var/log/mackerel-agent.log` みたいですが、設定ファイル(mackerel-agent.conf)を編集する必要があるかもしれません。

[mackerel-agent仕様](https://mackerel.io/ja/docs/entry/spec/agent)

**/etc/mackerel-agent/mackerel-agent.conf**

```
verbose = false   # <- true に変更
```